# Strip(remove) exported symbols from static lib

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization, libv8

I am embedding v8 in my exe and it's built as a static library, the result is an exe file after full optimization both in compiling and linking.
The total exe size is about 13MB .. I noticed that most of the v8 APIs are exported symbols in my exe.

an exported symbol in msvc can be marked with `_declspe(expot)` modifier

```
_declspec(export) type Name([args..]);
```

So, what flags can I use to stop and strip unused methods and symbols from being linked and exported?

my main goal is to reduce the size of the final exe file.

Comment: Um, `strip`? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/strip.html

Comment: mmm .. this solution is not for windows.

Comment: I use strip on Windows all the time.

Comment: does it work with exported symbols

Comment: what I need is a way to tell the linker to ignore exporting symbols from included static library and let the link to deside where its needed or not and never link them.

Comment: static libraries don't export symbols, they are simply concatenations of object files.

Comment: Are you sure your problem is the exports and not debug symbols? What does `dumpbin /exports` say?

Comment: sure .. my exe (for now) just uses helloworld example .. and includes v8 static libraries .. after building all v8 api function even unsef functions are exported

Comment: @NeilButterworth any function marked with _declspec even in static lib will be exported